# MMQGIS - grid hexagons

Tags: qgis, mmqgis

What parameters should be set (x spacing, y spacing, units) to get a 1 ha hexagon? I work in EPSG 32634 projection. QGIS plugin MMQGIS.

[image]

Regards,

Onosz

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Hexagon. I suppose you want to get regular hexagons so x spacing and y spacing should be equal.

Comment: Using a virtual layer of QGIS and
SELECT ST_HexagonalGrid (geometry, 62.04) as geom
FROM regions;

Where 62.04 is the side of the hex with area 10000 square meters

https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=tesselations-4.0

Comment: For 1 ha, `y = 2*L.sin 60º = 2*62.04032*0.866025403784 = 107.456986358 m` (please, see my answer).

Comment: The value y = 107.456986358 returned the hexagon area of ​​1 ha. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out (see next image) that these are relations among different distances in a regular hexagon used for MMQGIS plugin; where formula to calculate area as function of L is: A = 2.60*L<sup>2</sup>. So, if area is 1 ha (10000 m<sup>2</sup>) then L = 62.04032 m.

[image]

By geometric considerations, sin 60º = (y/2)/L and:

> y = 2*L.sin 60º = 2*62.04032*0.866025403784 = 107.456986358 m

As x and y are joined, you only need to put, at correspondent place in plugin, only calculated y value (x value is automatically calculated).

[image]

After click in OK, I got:

[image]

By using my plugin to calculate areas, I corroborated that it was ~10000 m2 for one particular feature; as expected.