# Failing to create a grid with hexagonal units

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.18, hexagonal-grid

I followed this [tutorial](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/248071/mmqgis-grid-hexagons) step by step. 
[image: My Grid Extent and Spacing]

However, when running the algorithm I get the following error:

> "Horizontal spacing is too small for the covered area"

I'm using EPSG 3857 (WGS 84 Pseudo Mercator) and I'm trying to obtain a 1 HA just as stated in the question I linked. This happens whether I increase or decrease the grid extent or horizontal and vertical spacing. The same error occurs with other projections (4326, 32644, 3763)

Using QGIS 2.18.16

Comment: I question the wisdom of trying to do any areal computations using a projection with highly unreliable distance calculations. An Equal-Area projection would be far more suitable (and may be less likely to give this error).

Comment: @Vince The same error occurs with all the other projections I am using in my work. (4326; 3763 and 25829)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the x and y spacing values and their unit plus the extent values that you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the grid extent values you used:

- xmin: -11.3
- xmax: -6.7
- ymin: 35.8
- ymax: 38.6

These look like decimal degree values (ie, latitude and longitude). However, the selected coordinate system (EPSG 32644) uses meters.

You're telling QGIS to make a 500 meter wide grid inside an area that is 4.6 by 2.2 meters. A 500 meter wide hexagon doesn't fit inside 4.6 meters.

**Solution: use grid extent values in meters**

Use the Coordinate Capture tool to find the coordinates of the corners of your extent. Be sure to set the CRS of the Coordinate Capture tool to the same CRS that you'll use for the grid tool.